# How can I source never changing data to a drop down in my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have many views which will all contain a drop-down select list to show status. Three different and non-changing values of status "Release", "Review" and "New". I keep hearing that my controller should provide all the data for my view but does that even apply for static data like this.

Can anyone suggest how I should best code up this select box?

Note this is for C# ASP.NET MVC3

Comment: Can you give us a clue about which language(s) and frameworks you are using? In the Spring MVC/Java world, this kind of data is called "reference data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is a bit different from the above.

Somewhere you'd should have a base model or a base controller (model fits better for my solution).

In that class stick a method like this

```
        public static SelectList MakeSelectListStatus(IEnumerable Coll, bool emptyElem = true)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> Items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            if (emptyElem)
                Items.Add((new SelectListItem { Text = " ", Value = "-1" }));
            foreach (var Elem in Coll)
            {
                SelectListItem AddMe = new SelectListItem();
                AddMe.Text = Elem.Descr;
                AddMe.Value = Elem.ID.ToString();
                Items.Add(AddMe);
            }
            SelectList Res = new SelectList(Items, "Value", "Text");
            return Res;
        }
```

Then in your views just use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, BaseModel.MakeSelectListStatus(Model.Statuses, false), new { id = "Statuses" })
```

Two big advantage in this method:
1. you don't have HTML magic strings anywhere
2. if your collections are designed properly, you can have one method for instancing every selectlist

The main disadvantage is having a base model, but can be easily solved with a static class somewhere.

However if you feel like having an helper is better for you, I suggest you to have an helper returning the SelectList object, not the HTML markups, don't know exactly why, but I consider it more versatile.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

If it is completely static you could just create a helper for it in the **App_Code** folder:

```
@helper StatusList()
{
  <select id="status-list">
     <option></option>
     <option value="Release">Release</option>
     <option value="Review">Review</option>
     <option value="New">New</option>
   </select>
}
```

and call it from the different views:

```
@StatusList()
```

**OR**

use a partial view in Views\Shared:

```
<select id="status-list">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Release">Release</option>
    <option value="Review">Review</option>
    <option value="New">New</option>
</select>
```

and render the partial from each view:

```
@Html.Partial("_StatusList")
```

**OR**

to do it from C# and the controller create a shared Helper Class:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStatusList()
    {
        var items = new[] { "Release", "Review", "New" };
        return items.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x,
            Text = x
        });
    }
}
```

add these properties to each ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; } 
public string StatusListSelectedValue { get; set; }
```

and this on each View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StatusListSelectedValue, Model.StatusList, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums are a good way to go when the categories never change. I have a full example at [Using the DropDownList and ListBox with ASP.NET MVC](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-the-DropDownList-67f9367d)

```
        public enum eMovieCategories { Action, Drama, Comedy, Science_Fiction };

    private void SetViewBagMovieType(eMovieCategories selectedMovie) {

        IEnumerable<eMovieCategories> values =
                          Enum.GetValues(typeof(eMovieCategories))
                          .Cast<eMovieCategories>();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
            from value in values
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = value.ToString(),
                Value = value.ToString(),
                Selected = value == selectedMovie,
            };

        ViewBag.MovieType = items;
    }

    public ActionResult SelectCategoryEnum() {
        SetViewBagMovieType(eMovieCategories.Drama);
        return View("SelectCategory");
    }
```

View

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Category Select";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Simple_Layout.cshtml";
```

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("CategoryChosen", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {
    
            Movie Type
            @Html.DropDownList("MovieType")

Send me an email and I'll shoot you the tutorial. Rick.anderson at microsoft.com